# How to update the widget with updated canvas?

Tags: python, pyqt5, grid-layout, qwidget, qtwidgets

When the button is clicked a plot is generated from 10 random integers. This works fine when the button is first clicked, but after that the graph does not refresh again and no change is observed. How can I update the widget with the updated canvas?

My code is shown below as well as the UI layout (myfileui.ui)

`main.py`:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg

[form_class,QMainWindow]=uic.loadUiType('myuifile.ui')

class MplCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):

    def __init__(self):
        fig = Figure()
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(fig)

class Main(form_class, QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.plot_graph)

    def plot_graph(self):
        x=range(10)
        y=np.random.randn(10)

        canvas = MplCanvas()
        canvas.axes.plot(x,y)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(canvas)

        self.widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.widget.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    app.exec_()
```

`myuifile.ui`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
  <class>Form</class>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
    <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <width>496</width>
        <height>404</height>
      </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="windowTitle">
      <string>Form</string>
    </property>
    <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
      <item row="0" column="0">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
          <property name="font">
            <font>
              <family>Consolas</family>
              <weight>75</weight>
              <bold>true</bold>
            </font>
          </property>
          <property name="text">
            <string>PushButton</string>
          </property>
        </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="1">
        <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
          <property name="orientation">
            <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
          </property>
          <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
            <size>
              <width>376</width>
              <height>20</height>
            </size>
          </property>
        </spacer>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="0" colspan="2">
        <widget class="QWidget" name="widget" native="true">
          <property name="font">
            <font>
              <family>Consolas</family>
              <weight>75</weight>
              <bold>true</bold>
            </font>
          </property>
          <property name="autoFillBackground">
            <bool>false</bool>
          </property>
          <property name="styleSheet">
            <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);</string>
          </property>
        </widget>
      </item>
    </layout>
  </widget>
  <resources/>
  <connections/>
</ui>
```

Here is a image of my application too:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the way you have structured the code and also because you are missing a couple of lines of code referring to `Canvas`.

The first thing is that I would recommend you to add the creation of the Canvas in the init, because doing it in the plot_graph every time you press the button would create a new canvas. You should also add your widget and its layout in the constructor, otherwise it would probably give problems when trying to setLayout a widget that already has a layout.

Finally you need to add delete the axes `self.canvas.axes.cla()` so they don't overlap and repaint it `self.canvas.draw()`.

Also, as you want to start with the graphic in hidden, you must add in the constructor a .hide() of the canvas (not of the widget, otherwise the layout would be out of order) and make the show when the button is pressed.

I attach the code below:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg

[form_class,QMainWindow]=uic.loadUiType('myuifile.ui')

class MplCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):

    def __init__(self):
        fig = Figure()
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(fig)

class Main(form_class, QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.canvas = MplCanvas()
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.widget.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.canvas.hide()

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.plot_graph)

    def plot_graph(self):
        self.canvas.axes.cla()
        x=range(10)
        y=np.random.randn(10)
        self.canvas.axes.plot(x,y)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.canvas.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your kindly answer. By the way, is there a method without using `self.canvas.cla()` and `self.canvas.draw()` and so just only update the widget, actually my application defines the canvas to plot different kinds of graphs, and the plotting part is defined in different classes and different kinds of methods. So I am looking for the method just change the final common part as the update only widget.

Comment: Que yo sepa hay que borrar los ejes (básicamente la "línea azul") y hay que volver a pintar, así que no creo que sea otro método. De todas formas, eso no debería de ser un problema ya que deberías podrías acceder al canvas sin problema (mediante parent, o cualquier otro método).

Answer (score 0):

Below codes works for me for updating graph without `canvas.axes.clear()` and `canvas.draw()`. I made newly the widget every time draw new graph and then using the `gridlayout.addWidget(widget)`.

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg

[form_class,QMainWindow]=uic.loadUiType('myuifile.ui')

# form_class=Ui_Form()

class MplCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):

    def __init__(self):
        fig = Figure()
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(fig)

class Main(form_class, QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.plot_graph)

    def plot_graph(self):
        x=range(10)
        y=np.random.randn(10)

        canvas = MplCanvas()
        canvas.axes.plot(x,y)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(canvas)

        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(widget, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        widget.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    app.exec_()
```